# What's the best way to integrate recurring payments on FirstData GGE4?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, recurring-billing, firstdata

After much trial and error I got my RSForms Pro Registration form to process payments through the GGE4 Web Services API. Now I need to use the TransArmor Token and Expiration date to automatically bill website subscribers.

I'm thinking some kind of combination of CRON Jobs and PHP/MySQL to perform a JSON request every day for any accounts that need to be billed for renewal.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, have you tried a combination of cron jobs and PHP/MySQL to perform a JSON request every day? Sounds like you know what you need to do...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to process the transarmor token transactions via the Hosted Payment using recurring. The API currently doesn't support recurring payments. The Realtime Payment Manager, the virtual terminal, doesn't support transarmor. If you punch in a transarmor token into RPM, it treats it as an invalid card time.

Hosted Payment is the way to go.